# Update yum fails

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos6, rhel

I'm using centOS 6.4.

I'm getting this error when I use "yum update" in the terminal window.

```
 Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Is there any alternative mirror for Upgrading?

Comment: try to change the name server to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: post the ouput of `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have DNS resolving problem

to check this run the command:

`nslookup  mirrorlist.centos.org`

if you dont get an  IP for answer  it means that your `/etc/resolv.conf` is not configured properly